# How to add new pages in OpenWRT Luci Web Interface?

Tags: ubuntu, lua, openwrt, luci

I am new in Luci openwrt. I want to add a new page or new tab in openwrt Luci Web Interface . This is the existing WebUI Interface and i want to add a page1 marked as red text  .

[image]

I can see all main pages in  `lib/lua/luci/controller/admin` path . like `/usr/lib/lua/luci/controller/admin/status.lua` . it's view page code in `/usr/lib/lua/luci/view/admin_status/syslog.htm` . This is fine . I understand.
These are my doubts  :

- Now i want to know how to add a new page in
  `lib/lua/luci/controller/admin` .  Can i add like
  `lib/lua/luci/controller/admin/page1.lua` and it's view like
  `/usr/lib/lua/luci/view/admin_status/page1.htm` ?
- where can i get the main HTML page in Luci ?

What are the steps should i follow to add a new page in openwrt? Any suggestions ?

Comment: I am not a Luci expert but i can answer your 2nd query, once you have compiled the openwrt build, you can find the mail HTML page inside "Openwrt/stagging_dir/target_...{target_board/architechture}/root_{board_type}/www" directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by adding a new .lua code in /lua/luci/controller/admin